# How to show slice value inside of slice in pie chart using chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, pie-chart

I am having an scenario, where I need to show the slice value inside of the slice in pie chart. I am having more  than 1 pie charts on my webpage. Below code is perfectly working but only for 1st Pie Chart and for others its throwing error as below, could you please help me to sort this out?

Error:: unCaught TypeError: cannot read the property 'data' of undefined.

```
 Code:: 
 options:{
 animation:{
 onComplete:function(){
      var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
      var dataset_obj = this.data.datasets;
      for (var i=0;i<dataset_obj.length; i++){
          var meta_obj = dataset_obj[i]._meta[i].data;
          for (var j=0; j<meta_obj.length; j++){
               var model =meta_obj[j]._model;
               start_angle= model.startAngle;
               end_angle = model.endAngle;
               mid_angle =start_angle + ( end_angle -start_angle)/2;
               mid_radius = model.innerRadius + (model.outerRadius -model.innerRadius)/2;
               var x =mid_radius*math.cos(mid_angle);
               var  y = mid_radius*math.cos(mid_angle);

               ctx.fillstyle='#fff';
               if (dataset_obj[i].data[j] != 0 && meta_obj[j].hidden != true){
                    ctx.fillText(dataset_obj[i].data[j], model.x+x, model.y+y);
               }
         }
      }
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: What about using the [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answers the issue contained in the question's title:

> How to show slice value inside of slice in pie chart using chart.js

The code snippet below show how to display the **values** inside the slices with the use of [`chartjs-plugin-labels`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-labels). The code of the samples was extracted from the `chartjs-plugin-labels` [demo page](https://emn178.github.io/chartjs-plugin-labels/samples/demo/).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'pie',    
    data: {
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
      datasets: [{
        data: [50445, 33655, 15900],
        backgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB','#FFCE56']
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      plugins: {
        labels: {
          render: 'value',
          fontColor: ['green', 'white', 'red']
        }
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

If you want to display the **percentage** of each slice, you can do the following:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'pie',    
    data: {
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
      datasets: [{
        data: [50445, 33655, 15900],
        backgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB','#FFCE56']
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      plugins: {
        labels: {
          render: 'percentage',
          fontColor: ['green', 'white', 'red'],
          precision: 2
        }
      },
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks @uminder, it's working but I am observing another problem as, these values are getting populated only oncea and when I reload the charts it's getting disappeared. Now let's say if I close the browser and open again or change the browser it will show values again. But after doing multiple force refresh cntrl+f5 then also it's not showing the values. Could you please help?

Comment: @Amit Moghe: Since it's working, please accept this answer and post a new question for the other problem you're observing now.

Comment: I have created another question for this, Please help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59816460/slice-values-are-getting-wiped-out-after-refreshing-pie-chart

Comment: this doesn't work for chartjs 3+