# Slice values are getting wiped out after refreshing Pie chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, pie-chart, chart.js2

I am using below code to populate slice values in a pie chart using JS and it's correctly working but
I am observing another problem as these values are getting populated only once and when I reload the charts it's getting disappeared. Now let's say if I close the browser and open again or change the browser it will show values again. But after doing multiple force refresh <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> then also it's not showing the values. Could you please help?

Please note I am having more than 3 pie charts on the same page with a different id.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
new Chart(canvas, {

    type: 'pie',    
    data: {
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
      datasets: [{
        data: [50445, 33655, 15900],
        backgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB','#FFCE56']
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      plugins: {
        labels: {
          render: 'percentage',
          fontColor: ['green', 'white', 'red'],
          precision: 2
        }
      },
    }
});
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: @uminder as discuss in another thread, will it be possible to for you to suggest possible cause and solution?

Comment: Can you see any error logged to the browser console?

Comment: @uminder : sorry but no error in browser console. if I open the charts on Chrome then for the first instance its showing values and then for 2nd run or if open on another chrome tab too then its not. if I open in IE its showing values.

Comment: Please note:: I am observing this issue specifically with Chrome browser